# Mac OS X clients cannot see extended ACLs through samba or netatalk on a debian server

Tags: linux, debian, mac-osx, samba, netatalk

I have set up a debian box as a replacement for an old windows server for my company's central file repository. I am using acl enabled ext3 filesystem.

We need to be able to use extended access control lists to control user access to files, and windows users recognise the acl's set just fine.

Mac OS X clients (running leopard 10.5) will not see the extended ACL's via samba or netatalk and I run into permissions errors.

Can someone please recommend a way around this? How can I get Mac OS X to recognise extended ACL's on linux? I am happy to change from debian to something else if need be, just as long as it is free ;-)

Comment: It seems that putting

[global]
unix extensions = no

In my /etc/samba/smb.conf has helped matters a little, now the mac client doesn't see permissions at all and assumes read/write access for everything - then fails when trying to write to a directory it shouldn't be able to.

Can anyone recommend any better work arounds? This seems a little hacky.

Answer (score 1):

Try this workaround:

Add

```
acl check permissions = no
```

to `[global]` because of how Darwin ACLs are closer to Windows ACLs instead of POSIX ACLs.

Sources:

- [Apple's Mac OS X Server Mailing List](http://lists.apple.com/archives/macos-x-server/2008/Jan/msg00760.html)
- [AFP548.com](http://www.afp548.com/forum/viewtopic.php?showtopic=18822)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but doesn't seem to work for me. I have set standard unix permissions to no access, then the ACL grants access. With acl check permissions = no, the acl is disregarded, and no one has access!

The work around I will have to go with is setting unix extensions = no. This lets the windows clients see ACLs fine, and the mac clients assume write capability to everything (until they try to write something). Directories they have no access to appear empty.

Ideally, I'd like to use netatalk for afp access for the macs, but it won't see the ACL's either! Would a different fs help?

Answer (score 0):

Samba protocol in Mac OS 10.12 uses ACLs in a similar way as Windows OS Samba. To get Samba ACL works in Mac OS and Window OS, suppose Samba server runs in Redhat OS 7, then in smb.conf, the following lines should be added to the global or the corresponding share section,

```
inherit acls = Yes # enable POSIX ACLs support
vfs objects = acl_xattr # enable Window ACLs support
map acl inherit = yes
store dos attributes = yes
```

For further info, check Samba Window support https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_Windows_ACLs